# How to get rid of list positions / line numbers in an output

Tags: r, list, function, readability

I want to display many results from a function but have read that you can only return one object and hence have to use a list if you want to show more. This works ok however the output is not very readable sometimes (in this fake example it's not too bad, at my work it is though). How can I get rid of or suppress these line/list positions that R has automatically added to my output?

Current output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "There are 5 total observations"

[[2]]
[1] "The mean of these observations is 0.564422113896047"

[[3]]
[1] "The observations are shown below:"

[[4]]
[1]  1.0496648  0.4807251  0.8536269  1.7946839 -1.3565901
```

Desired output:

```
"There are 5 total observations"


"The mean of these observations is 0.564422113896047"


"The observations are shown below:"


 1.0496648  0.4807251  0.8536269  1.7946839 -1.3565901
```

I'm happy to settle with being able to remove the double bracket outputs above each line but keep the line number outputs. If I could also alter the line spacing at individual points then that'd be better but not really required.

Code used to create this function / output:

```
test <- function(n_observations) {

  obs <- rnorm(n_observations)

return(list(
  paste0("There are ",n_observations," total observations"),
  paste0("The mean of these observations is ",mean(obs)),
  paste0("The observations are shown below:"),
  obs
))

}

test(n_observations = 5)
```

**EDIT:** 
Ronaks answer works fine in this situation since I didn't include a list/dataframe in this example. I've updated the function below to show the error that you encounter when you try it with one present, namely;

```
 test <- function(n_observations) {

  obs <- rnorm(n_observations)
  random_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1:n_observations), obs))

return(cat(
  paste0("There are ",n_observations," total observations\n"),
  paste("\n"),
  paste0("The mean of these observations is ",mean(obs),"\n"),
  paste0("The observations are shown below:\n"),
  obs,
  random_table
  ))
}

test(n_observations = 5)
```

Output (and error):

```
There are 5 total observations

 The mean of these observations is 0.445438123798109
 The observations are shown below:
 1.677665 1.379066 0.3436419 0.4783038 -1.651487 Error in cat(paste0("There are ", n_observations, " total observations\n"),  : 
  argument 6 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cat` if you want to improve the way your output is printed, including "\n" after every line to display output in different line.

```
test <- function(n_observations) {
   obs <- rnorm(n_observations)

   return(cat(
     paste0("There are ",n_observations," total observations\n"),
     paste0("The mean of these observations is ",mean(obs), "\n"),
     paste0("The observations are shown below:\n"),
     obs
   ))
}

test(n_observations = 5)

#There are 5 total observations
# The mean of these observations is -0.785794194405614
# The observations are shown below:
# -0.4806757 -0.6366636 0.3147989 -1.873661 -1.25277
```

---

**EDIT**

If we only want to display the results why get into `return`ing them, we can print them from the function itself.

```
test <- function(n_observations) {

  obs <- rnorm(n_observations)
  random_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1:n_observations), obs))


  cat(paste0("There are ",n_observations," total observations\n"),
  paste0("The mean of these observations is ",mean(obs), "\n"),
  paste0("The observations are shown below:\n"),
  obs, "\n\n The table is as below : \n\n")
  print(random_table)
}

test(n_observations = 5)

#There are 5 total observations
# The mean of these observations is 0.540141211615552
# The observations are shown below:
# 1.922104 -0.5334201 -0.9881913 1.838563 0.4616504 

# The table is as below : 

#  V1        obs
#1  1  1.9221042
#2  2 -0.5334201
#3  3 -0.9881913
#4  4  1.8385628
#5  5  0.4616504
```

The last `print(random_table)` can be avoided and we can only use `random_table` but I am assuming OP has many other things like this to `print` so it could be useful in that case.

Comment: Thank you for both examples, yes I have many different tables to display but your method works nicely with this.